# Why does the prop not change to true?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, prop

If I call this in parent comp:

```
 private addEmployeeForm() {
return <AddEmployeeComp employees={this.state.employees} showForm={true} />;


}
```

And then AddEmployeeComp:

```
    export class AddEmployeeComp extends React.Component<
  { employees: Employee[]; showForm: boolean },
  {
    
    showEmployeeForm: boolean;
  }
> {
  
  constructor(props: { employees: Employee[]; showForm: boolean }) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showEmployeeForm: this.props.showForm,
    };
  }




   private handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      showEmployeeForm: false,
    });
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.showEmployeeForm ? (
          <div className="popup-box">
            <div className="box">
              <span className="close-icon" onClick={() => this.handleClose()}>
                x
              </span>
              <div className="userNameDiv">
                <label className="labelUsername" htmlFor="username">
                  Username
                </label>
                <br />
    ...
```

Why does the showForm={true} not apply, once I closed the Formular (AddEmployeeCmp) and I want to open it again. showForm is after the first open always set to false. How could I change it to true again (from parent comp)?

Comment: Once the handleClose() method is called, which sets the state of showEmployeeForm to false, there is no mechanism to change it back to true from the parent component. To change showForm back to true from the parent component, you can create a state variable in the parent component that tracks the value of showForm. For example, in the parent component, you can add a state variable isAddEmployeeFormOpen that tracks whether the AddEmployeeComp component is opened or closed

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I track that, if I close the form inside of my child component? How can my parent get that data?

Comment: So, as far as I'm concerned, create a function in your parent component, that changes the boolean variable opened/closed and you pass that function to the child and then call the function. This will result in re-rendering component with an updated variable.

Here is a short code demo of what I'm talking about: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-qkqgdv?file=index.ts

Comment: *(it's not displaying anything, but you need to just look at the toggleAddEmployeeForm() function and try to implement it to your code with the same working principle)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showForm` is props and `showEmployeeForm` is state. `showForm` only initializes `showEmployeeForm`. If you want parent know its child componet's state change, you may need to lift the state up. See React doc [sharing-state-between-components](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components)
and [lifting-state-up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).